# Is it bad to make your JFrame a static variable? (Java swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Is it bad programming to make a JFrame static? The reason why I currently am declaring my JFrame as a static variable is because I had a JPanel instantiated inside of it and I needed to send information to the JFrame on certain events and the only way I could do that was declaring the JFrame statically in my main and then calling up a method in the JFrame that calls up a method in my JPanel.

Comment: I think you should provide code about your current problem, then you'll get a better answer of your question, now is dificcult to understand. I can't understand what you mean by `I currently am declaring my JFrame as a static variable is because I had a JPanel instantiated inside of it and I needed to send information to the JFrame` that's has no sense for me at all unless you show some valid code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Not that it is necessarily wrong, but you don't need to have the JFrame be static for the reason you cite. You could have in the constructor to your subclass of JPanel an argument that is the JFrame it lives in. Better yet, you can abstract up a level GUI events from logical events, and have an object that both the JFrame and JPanel can see that acts as a pub-sub channel.

Answer (score 4):

Using static isn't inherently good or bad, as long as you're using it for the right reasons.

However, it sounds like you're using the static keyword for the wrong reasons, making it "easier" to pass information between classes. The problem with this approach is that it will make it much harder to expand your program in the future: what happens if you want to have two instances of the class that contains the static variable? You'll have to rewrite a bunch of code, so it's best to avoid using static as a "shortcut" to sharing data.

Instead, pass the instance of the JFrame to the class or method that creates the JPanel.

Comment: I instantiate the JPanel inside the JFrame. Should I create a class that instantiates them both?

Comment: Whatever makes the most sense to you and your context. You could create a class that instantiates both. What happened when you tried that? You could also pass a reference to the JFrame into the JPanel. Up to you.

Answer (score 3):

In a larger program you might run into trouble using it for the reasons you stated -- both from the `static`-ness itself and the fact that it would indicate a larger design flaw (and imply that a lot more serious problems existed). For a simple one-off, it's not ideal but it sounds like it gets the job done for you, just be sure you document why you did it in the comments.

In general, though, there are much more appropriate ways of doing that, e.g. proper use of event listeners, inheritance, etc.

For example, if your `JFrame` creates a child `JPanel` and you need to access that `JPanel` from elsewhere, consider implementing methods in your `JFrame`-derived class that expose the relevant functionality, instead of trying to directly manipulate the `JPanel` from outside.

Comment: +1 Well stated.  The only minor thing I'd add is Singletons (which make testing far easier than static methods and add more control over the object).  Most of my serious applications have a Singeton controller that provides high-level operations.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adopting the following paradigm in the class that holds your static main

```
public class MyMainClass {
    private static MyMainClass me;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        me = new MyMainClass();
        me.start(args);
    }
    private void start(String[] args) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

> the only way I could do that was declaring the JFrame statically in my main and then calling up a method in the JFrame that calls up a method in my JPanel

You can easily define a class that derives from JPanel and adds a variable to hold a reference to a JFrame; then you can call methods of the JFrame (which is likely to be your own custom JFrame subclass) in the event handler methods of your panel class.

The JPanel.getParent() method is likely to **not** return the JFrame, but rather its contentPane or the like; don't waste time with it.